# Returning Multiple Columns from FuzzyWuzzy token_set_ratio

Tags: python-3.x, fuzzywuzzy

I am attempting to perform some fuzzy matching across two datasets containing lots of addresses.

I am iterating through a list of addresses in df, and finding the 'most matching' out of another:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():  
    test_address = df.Full_Address[row] 
    first_comp = fuzz.token_set_ratio(df3.Full_Address,`test_address)
```

taking the row output returns me the full address from df, but I can't come up with a way to return the subsequently 'matched' address from df3.

Can anyone give a pointer please?

df ~ 18k rows
df3 ~ 2.5M rows
Which obviously presents limitations:

I have tried using np.meshgrid to create a list of values & get ratio for each value pair then select rows greater than the threshold.
Also tried this but with the dataset size it takes an age

```
matched_names =[]    
for row1 in df.index:
    name1 = df.get_value(row1,"Full_Address") 
    for row2 in df3.index:
        name2= df3.get_value(row2,"Full_Address")  
        matched_token=fuzz.token_set_ratio(name1,name2)
        if matched_token> 80:
            matched_names.append([name1,name2,matched_token])
            print(matched_names)
```